# How to serialize ASObject to JSON

Tags: json, jackson

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize `flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject` to JSON. `ASObject` extends HashMap and adds an additional type property. By default Jackson correctly serializes all the keys and values under the object, but doesn't preserve the `ASObject.getType()`.

Using Jackson I've managed to create a custom serializer for `ASObject` and am now serializing as:

```
[{"@type":"org.me.MyClass","map":{"key":"value"}}]
```

This was by adding an additional type field then delegating back to the standard handler for `java.util.Map`. However I'm not sure how I can configure Jackson to allow custom deserialization to allow custom handling of this.

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to create custom deserializer as well? You may not really need that type field as long as type is known from context when deserializing (property has ASOBject type).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonMethod;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationContext;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonDeserializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;

public class JacksonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ASObject asObject = new ASObject();
    asObject.type = Bar.class;
    asObject.put("1", "alpha");
    asObject.put("TWO", "beta");

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule", Version.unknownVersion());
    module.addSerializer(ASObject.class, new ASObjectSerializer());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().withModule(module).setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    String asObjectJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(asObject);
    System.out.println(asObjectJson);
    // output: {"type":"com.stackoverflow.q8158528.Bar","map":{"1":"alpha","TWO":"beta"}}

    module = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule", Version.unknownVersion());
    module.addDeserializer(ASObject.class, new ASObjectDeserializer());
    mapper = new ObjectMapper().withModule(module).setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    ASObject asObjectCopy = mapper.readValue(asObjectJson, ASObject.class);
    System.out.println(asObjectCopy.equals(asObject));
    // output: true
  }
}

class ASObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ASObject>
{
  @Override
  public ASObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    ASObject asObject = new ASObject();
    JsonNode tree = jp.readValueAsTree();
    try
    {
      asObject.type = Class.forName(tree.get("type").asText());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      System.exit(42);
    }
    asObject.putAll(jp.getCodec().treeToValue(tree.get("map"), Map.class));
    return asObject;
  }
}

class ASObjectSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ASObject>
{
  @Override
  public void serialize(ASObject value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
      JsonProcessingException
  {
    jgen.writeStartObject();
    jgen.writeStringField("type", value.type.getName());
    jgen.writeObjectField("map", new HashMap(value));
    jgen.writeEndObject();
  }
}

class ASObject extends HashMap
{
  Class type;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o)
  {
    ASObject a = (ASObject) o;
    return type.equals(a.type) && super.equals(a);
  }
}

class Bar
{
}
```